# SSLHandshakeException when response is 204 (No Content)

Tags: android, ssl

So, I have a little bit of code that looks like this:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(url_raw);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    /*snip*/
    connection.connect();
    int response_code = connection.getResponseCode(); <-- Error here
/*snip*/
```

- When the url returns 204 with no content, I get an exception thrown.
- When the url returns 204 but has content anyway, I get an exception thrown.
- When the url returns any non-204 code with content, I'm fine. (Like, say, 200 with a "success" message).

The error log is here:

```
W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5f5d07c0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err﹕ error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5d908d74:0x00000000)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
```

I could work around the problem by never returning 204 but it just seems like too much of a hack =/

Comment: If you got a URL return code of anything, the handshake must have succeeded. If you got a handshake exception you can't possibly have also got a URL return code. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
```

According to this trace it fails inside the initial TLS handshake. The TLS handshake of a HTTPS connection must be finished before the HTTP request is sent and before the HTTP response is read. Since it fails already within the TLS handshake and thus before the status code is received the problem cannot be related to the status code itself.

Instead you need to look at the server side for implementation errors and not at the client side. My guess is that the server is broken and does not do any TLS handshake in case of 204, but given that no information about this server are provided this is just a wild guess.